# How to change codepage of files to make it usable on IBM/Toshiba 4690 OS?

Tags: character-encoding, codepages

I've files with various languages. Tried Notepad ++ and cpconverter but they didnt help as some codepages like codepage 942 or codepage 1381 are not available.

This is an image from IBM machine running on 4690 OS

[image: This is an image from IBM machine running on 4690 OS]

Answer (score 0):

If it is in binary format, Please make use any of the Hex editor tools to view the contents of the file but before that you should be well versed about the contents (ex: TLOG strings if its Transaction data) to understand the details.